# MongoDB max values query and _id

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

db.collections.find()

```
    { "_id" : ObjectId("55b0c2a0339bf8d00ab0bade"), "score" : 46, "playerid" : "45"}
    { "_id" : ObjectId("55b0c2de339bf8d00ab0badf"), "score" : 88, "playerid" : "45"}
    { "_id" : ObjectId("55b0cbca17f398f4281ab931"), "score" : 46, "playerid" : "99"}
    { "_id" : ObjectId("55b15ababe2df0f430d1cb93"), "score" : 89, "playerid" : "45"}
```

What I'm trying to do, is retrieve all documents with the largest score. If the same player occurs more than once, then we get the document with the largest score for that particular player.

The result would look like this:

```
    { "_id" : "55b0cbca17f398f4281ab931", "score" : 46 }
    { "_id" : "55b15ababe2df0f430d1cb93", "score" : 89 }
```

This is where I'm stuck:

```
db.players.aggregate([

{ "$group": { 
    "_id": "$playerid",
    score: { $max: "$score" }
} }
])
```

which returns:

```
    { "_id" : "99", "score" : "46" }
    { "_id" : "45", "score" : "89" }
```

Now, this is correct. But I just need the ObjectID instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of [**`$max`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) then use [**`$sort`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) and [**`$first`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) where the other properties are important to you:

```
db.players.aggregate([
   { "$sort": { "score": -1 } },
   { "$group": { 
       "_id": "$playerid",
       "docId": { "$first": "$_id" },
       "score": { "$first": "$score" }
   }}
])
```

The `$max` operator of course only works on "one" field that you specify. In order to get detail from the collection document then you need to `$sort` and get the `$first` occurance on the grouping boundary.

Of course `$first` is relative to the `$sort` order which is "descending", otherwise use [**`$last`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/) with ascending order, for the "maximum" value on the sort key.